# Can't see my gridview on page load from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I made an easy example of gridview and dunno why, but the gridview not exists on the website at all.

Here is the picture what I get in the browser - Nothing... http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/example.1414716455.jpg

Can somebody see any mistake?

```
<%@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeFile="InvoiceEdit.aspx.cs" Inherits="InvoiceEdit" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
  <style>
.gridview 
{
    background: red;
    border:dashed 1px blue;
}
</style>
  <asp:GridView ID="gvInvoice" runat="server"            
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvInvoice_RowDataBound"
    DataKeyNames="InvoiceID"   
    AutoGenerateEditButton="False" 
    CellPadding="1" Width="100%" 
    datasourceid="SqlDataSource1"
    CssClass ="gridview">
<Columns >
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="InvoiceID" DataField="InvoiceID" ReadOnly="true" /> 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RechnNummer" DataField="RechnNummer" ReadOnly="true" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Kunde" DataField="Kunde" ReadOnly="true" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="Text" ReadOnly="true"/>            
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
----TEST TEXT----
<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"          
    selectcommand="Select * from Invoice where InvoiceID = @InvoiceID"
    updatecommand="Update Invoice set RechnNummer = @RechnNummer, Kunde=@Kunde, Text=@Text, RechnDatum=@RechnDatum, Netoo=@Netoo,
                  Umsatzsteuer=@Umsatzsteuer, Brutto=@Brutto, Eingang=@Eingang where InvoiceID = @InvoiceID"        
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Invoice%>"
    runat="server" >    
    <SelectParameters> 
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvInvoice" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="InvoiceID" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvInvoice" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="InvoiceID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
  </asp:sqldatasource>
</asp:Content>
```

Code-behind is almost empty, but I think it doesn't matter... maybe some library is missing? or what is wrong? thanks for the answers!

```
public partial class InvoiceEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {      
    }

    protected void gvInvoice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { 
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",    "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#C2C2C2'");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout","this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;");
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Check your data source. Are you getting any data?

Comment: take please a look at this picture, http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/example.1414719295.jpg if i use design mode, i can see that gridview, but i cant edit it there...hm. Sadly, but i dont get any errors, it happens to me first time

Comment: Design mode is just showing you some dummy data. It doesn't mean you get data from the Database. Have a look at your data source. Where's your connection string? Check whether its correct

Comment: You can just test your SQL datasource just to see whether its connecting to the database

Comment: my connectionstring is in the WebConfig http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/example.1414720209.jpg I have still one big project on this PC, it has the same shema and it works >.<

Comment: Even if your other project uses the same schema and working perfectly doesn't mean that all the other projects should work. Your SQL datasource is the issue. Test it individually in design mode.

Comment: but the problem is, if i had wrong connection properties i would get an error by debugging. ANd thats dissapointing me, i already tryed anything... but yeah, you are right! 1 moment i ll post still one picture

Comment: here is one http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/example.1414722300.jpg all the same between 2 projects with that "connection strings" dono why is it so, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Either add a new connection or proceed next (in your screen that you posted just now) until you see "Test Query" button. Press it and see whether you get data.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-SqlDataSource-pass-value-to-SelectParameter-using-QueryString-Parameter-Example.aspx).

Add a textfield:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoiceID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Change Select statement and Select Parameter on the datasource code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Invoice %>"
    SelectCommand="Select * from Invoice where InvoiceID = @InvoiceID OR @InvoiceID IS NULL" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="InvoiceID" DbType = "String" Direction = "Input" QueryStringField="Id" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtInvoiceID.Text = Request.QueryString["Id"];
    }
}

protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?Id=" + txtInvoiceID.Text.Trim());
}
```

You must add SQL Parameter.. There is no data at the datagrid, so the datagrid invisible.

Comment: Thanks, but i was working for all night and i finaly solved this problem. The SQL connection was bugged (dono why), i just did it still one time from null